# Turning off a worksheet change-based event macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've been stuck on this for awhile. I have a macro that runs every time a change is made and creates a data table that updates after each change with information like : Old Value, New Value, Data Changes, etc.

I am trying to kind of pause the worksheet change macro when I don't want it to be run anymore. Ex: If I am plugging in blank information, I don't need to document the fact that it used to be blank, and now it has data, etc.

I made some specifications for if I deleted an entire row as shown here:

```
If Target.Address = Target.EntireRow.Address Then Exit Sub
```

but that only dealt with one case. I just now thought of a very simple solution that I will post as the answer, so I hope this will help other people as much as it helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a very simple solution.

To begin pick a cell that has no information in but can be clearly located. For the purpose of this lets say A1.

Now pick key words that you will use to turn the macro on and off. Ex: I just chose True and False (capitals need to be consistent so pick what you want)

At this point, go to the beginning of your worksheet change macro and type in this right after the sub starts:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("A1").Value = "False" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Now, before your macro starts, it will always verify that the cell doesn't contain False, so if you want it on, put anything else but False, and if you want it off, keep the cell as False. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is actually a pretty common practice. Others won't go for a cell though, too risky. I personally use a named formula if I ever had to do this, but I don't. Sometimes, I just use a simple `Application.EnableEvents = False` in any case I don't want any change event macros to run while I'm doing something.

Comment: Yeah I think in this case this works better, because my macro ends up jotting a lot of information when a change is made, and I'm already using a lot of EnableEvents throughout it. I also locked the cell with a password. However, I do agree that that is a viable way of doing it though.

Comment: There was also no way to specify when and when not to use the macro. There were wayyyy too many cases

Comment: If you have to use a lot of `EnableEvents`, there's a possibility your code is dealing with a lot of redundancies. That's not good. But in any case, if this works, it works. The only issue I have with this is that your `Range("A1")` is not defined properly. Assuming this macro is in `Sheet1` and I run a macro in `Sheet2` changing a cell in `Sheet1`. This won't actually check `Sheet1`'s `A1`. Rather, it will check `Sheet2`'s `A1`. Obviously, this can cause problems down the line. In any case, just qualify `Range("A1")` properly, regardless of where the code is located.

Comment: Yea this only deals with Sheet 1 so it doesn't run into that problem

Answer (score 1):

You want to disable events while ensuring that you enable them later. To do this, use an error handler to catch all errors and set the state back at the end.

```
Public Sub example()
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' => disable events
    
    'The code ...

errHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' => enable events
    
End Sub
```